# React material-table cellEditable: empty value and editable prop based on another cell value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm using material-table in my react app, and I have 2 questions regarding cellEditable:

1. if one of my cell-values is undefined I can't edit it. how can I change that behaviour?
2. I want that one column will be editable only if another column has a specific value, how can I have the rowData in the editable prop of the cell value?

my code looks like this:

```
/* initial value of the node is: { branches: [{ name: "Node 1", isList: false }] } */
const { node } = props; 

<MaterialTable
  icons={tableIcons}
  title="Branches Table"
  columns={[
    {
      field: 'name',
      title: 'Name',
      editable: node.isReference ? 'never' : 'always',
    },
    {
      field: 'isList',
      title: 'List',
      editable: 'never',
      render: rowData => (
        <Checkbox
          checked={rowData.isList}
          onChange={e => updateBranch(rowData.guid, {
            isList: e.target.checked,
            max: undefined,
          })}
          disabled={rowData.type === useTypes.TYPE_OF}
       />
      ),
    },
    {
      field: 'max',
      title: 'Max',
      type: 'numeric' as "numeric",
    },
  data={node.branches}
  cellEditable={{
    onCellEditApproved: (newValue, oldValue, rowData, columnDef) =>
      Promise.resolve(updateBranch(rowData.guid, { [String(columnDef.field)]: newValue })),
  }}
/>
```

and in the browser it looks like this:

[image]

first, I can't edit the "max" column as its inital value is undefined, and I want to be able to edit it.

second, I want the "max" to be editable only if "isList" is true. something like `editable: rowData => rowData.isList ? "always" : "never"` but I don't have the rowData in the "editable" prop of the column.

Comment: did u try initialEditValue in max?